# Why can't my browser access CSS or Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring-mvc, browser

I am working on Eclipse and using Spring MVC. My project structure is like this:[image]

Inside the `css` folder, I have all the CSS files. Inside the `js` folder, I have all the Javascript files.

Here is my controller class:

```
    package hellocontroller;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/greet")
    public class HelloController
    {

        @RequestMapping("/hi")
        protected ModelAndView Hi()
        {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("HomePage");
            modelAndView.addObject("welcomeMessage","Hi user. hi");

            return modelAndView;
        }

    }
```

My HomePage.jsp looks like this:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Mytuition home</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/ButtonsClass.css">
</head>
<body>
-- here i have used the css class

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

But my browser can't access the files in the `css` or `js` folders. When I type 
http://localhost:8080/Mytuition/greet/hi 
I get error on console and no CSS or Javascript gets applied to it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/
I had to change both the JSP file and the dispatcher-servlet.